# Assigning variable in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is it possible to assign a variable within a list comprehension?
For example, I want to write a list comprehension with this example, am I able to set my variable "set_" in my list comprehension? (I do not want to use the walrus expression)

```
people = ['John has a cat','Sarah has a dog','David has a cat','Peter has a cat']
names = ['John','Peter']

output = []
for i in people:
    set_ = i.split(' ')
    if set_[3] == 'cat' and set_[0] in names:
        output.append(i)
```

Comment: `[i for i in people if i.split()[3]=='cat' and i.split()[0] in names]`?

Comment: A list comprehension is a tool for efficiently creating a list according to the logic. Is you question how to make the list, and _also_ to have a usable `set_` variable left over afterward> Because that is not possible. If your question is just how to incorporate the `i.split(' ')` logic into the comprehension, that's very acheivable

Comment: @G.Anderson Given that only the last value of `set_` is accessible after the loop completes, I think it's safe to assume  the latter.

Comment: @chepner I don't disagree, but it's ambiguous enough that I felt a clarification request was in order. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In Python 3.8, you can use the assignment expression.

```
output = [i for i in people if (set_ := i.split(' '))[3] == 'cat' and set_[0] in names]
```

Prior to Python 3.8, you would need a second `for` clause with a singleton iterable.

```
output = [i for i in people for set_ in [i.split()] if set_[3] == 'cat' and set_[0] in names]
```

The assignment expression was added precisely to avoid the need for the second `for` clause.

Comment: can you explain why the solution by SuperStew is not the best way to move forward?

Comment: Because you unnecessarily call `i.split` twice. Aside from the runtime overhead, there's a maintenance issue: if the format of your string changes, there are two calls to `i.split()` to adjust rather than just one.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same result by pulling the if-check outside the comprehension:

```
def check(i):
    set_ = i.split(' ')
    return set_[3] == 'cat' and set_[0] in names

output = [i for i in people if check(i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
people = ['John has a cat','Sarah has a dog','David has a cat','Peter has a cat']
names = ['John','Peter']


output = [i for i in people if i.split()[3]=='cat' and i.split()[0] in names]
```

Output is -> `['John has a cat', 'Peter has a cat']`

Answer (score 0):

For that particular example I would suggest using unpacking to make the list comprehension clearer:

```
output = [p for p in people for name,_,_,pet in [p.split()] if name in names and pet == "cat" ]
```

you could also use map to break the strings in a single for loop:

```
output = [" ".join(p) for p in map(str.split,people) if p[0] in names and p[3] == "cat" ]
```

or zip and map to avoid rebuilding the strings:

```
output = [p for p,(name,_,_,pet) in zip(people,map(str.split,people)) if name in names and pet == "cat"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Whats wrong with

```
output=[i for i in people if i.split(' ')[3]=='cat' and i.split(' ')[0] in names]
```

Comment: The unnecessary second call to `i.split()` is what most people would object to.